# General equilibrium papers on universal basic income

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, general-equilibrium, basic-income

Are there any microeconomics or general equilibrium articles on [universal basic income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_income)?

Papers dealing with general wealth transfer mechanisms where a basic universal income would be a subset of the general transfer mechanism discussed are also fine.

Comment: Not general equilibrium in the strict sense, but [this paper](http://rooseveltinstitute.org/modeling-macroeconomic-effects-ubi/) might be worth to look at.

Comment: just read that paper - very informative!